# Python regex matching is not able to match *

Tags: python, regex

Need help in understanding the following examples.

```
>>> re.search('*.script', 'a.script')
Traceback (most recent call last):
<snipped>
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
>>> re.search('\*.script', 'a.script')
>>> re.search('a.script', 'a.script')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='a.script'>
>>> re.search(r'\*.script', 'a.script')
>>> re.search(r'\\*.script', 'a.script')
<re.Match object; span=(1, 8), match='.script'>
>>> re.search(r'\\\\*.script', 'a.script')
>>> re.search(r'\\\*.script', 'a.script')
>>> re.search('\\*.script', 'a.script')
>>>
```

When I escape the *, there is no match. When I escape it twice, only .script is matched. How can I use `*.script` as regex and match the full string `a.script`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern: `r".*\.script"`. (It will match anything that ends in `.script`).

You need to escape the `.` if you want to match the char `.`. If you don't escape it you will match any char. `.` Has a special meaning inside a regex!

To get what you asked using search you just have to index with `[]`:

`re.search(r".*\.script", 'a.script')[0]`

Comment: `re.search(r"\\*\.script", 'a.script')`

`<re.Match object; span=(1, 8), match='.script'>`

How can we get a full match `a.script`?

Comment: Also, how can I force it to match from the beginning of the string to the end? When I use ^ character, it doesn't force it to match from the start.
`re.search(r"\\*\.script$", 'a.script')`
`<re.Match object; span=(1, 8), match='.script'>`
`re.search(r"^\\*\.script$", 'a.script')`
Suprisingly, `$` works.

Comment: There was a mistake in my regex... I misundertood your question. `\\*` is what you need to match the `*`... But if you want to match any amount of chars you achieve it with `.*`. Check the edit I made

Comment: to force matching the whole string would be: `re.search(r"^.*\.script$", 'a.script')`